# Vigenere cipher, how to deal with ordinal values out of range of character values

Tags: python, encryption, vigenere

i am a student doing my coursework where we have to make a Vigenere cipher program. 
i know my program is complicated but i don't know of any other way of doing it and its too late to fix it.
i seem to have a problem with when i add the ordinal values of the message and keyword the new ordinal values are out of range of the normal alphabet values. so it prints weird letters like this ÐÑÐÑÐÑÐÑÐÑÐÑÐÑÐÑ.

here is my code:

```
newmessage1 = []
stringposition = 0
number1 = 0
mesletter = 0
keyletter = 0
output =[]
keylist = []
stringofnumbs = []
question = input('Would you like to encrypt, decrypt a message or quit?')
encdec=[]
if question == 'encrypt'or'encrypt a string'or'ENCRYPT'or'encrypt_a_message'or'Encrypt':
    message1 = input('Please input a message to encrypt')
    keyword1 = input('Please input a keyword ')
    if message1.isalpha and keyword1.isalpha:#this check if the message and the keyword only contains letters
        messagelength=len(message1)#this sets the variable 'messagelength' to the length of message1
        newkeyword=''#this is an empty variable used to insert the length of the new keyword
        while len(keyword1)<=len(message1):#this will loop checks that the length of keyword1 is smaller thasn the length of message1.
            keyword1+=keyword1#this will repeat the keyword to fit the length of the message
            newkeyword=keyword1[:len(message1)]
            #this set the 'newkeyword' variable to the length of the new keyword
            #(the new keyword is the keyword repeated to fit the length of the message.) 

            for mesletter in message1:
                mesnumber = ord(mesletter)#what it does is it takes every letter in message1 and puts it into its unicode form.
                stringofnumbs.append(mesnumber)#once one letter has been put in its unicode value it will append that unicdoe from of that
                #letter in the variable 'stringofnumbs',it will do this process for every letter in the message. 

            for keyletter in keyword1:
                keynumber = ord(keyletter)#what it does is it takes every letter in keyword1 and puts it into its unicode form.
                keylist.append(keynumber)#once one letter has been put in its unicode value it will
                #append that unicdoe from of that letter in the variable 'stringofnumbs',it will do this process for every letter in the message.

                temp1 = int(stringofnumbs[stringposition])#temp1 is a variable that holds the ordinal values of letters in message1
                temp2 = int(keylist[stringposition-1])#and temp2 is a variable that holds the ordinal values of letters in the keyword1
                temp3 = temp2+temp1#temp3 then adds these ordinal values togther 
                encdec.append(temp3)#the ordinal values added togther are appended to the encdec variable

            for number1 in encdec:
                newletter1=chr(number1)#this for loop takes every letter in encdec and puts the ordinal values back into charcters
                newmessage1.append(newletter1)#then every letter that has been changed to a charcater value is appended to the varibale newmessage1
            print (' ')#this leaves a bit of space to make the encoded text clear    
            print ('the endcoded text is:')#this is just a bit of text to make the encoded text clear to the user
            print (''.join(newmessage1))#here the encoded message is printed
    else:
        ('The message or keyword is invalid please use only numbers')#this will print only if the keyword or message doesnt only contain letters and spaces
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the most common solution to you problem is to "wrap" the numbers round again. That is, if you divide by the largest valid ordinal you want to permit, and use the remainder instead.

For instance, using `chr` as the inverse of `ord`:

```
In [0]: chr(122)    # I guess this is the last valid character you want?
Out[0]: 'z'

In [1]: chr(123)    # Because now we go into symbols
Out[1]: '{'

In [2]: 234%122    # We can take the remainder using modulo division
Out[2]: 112

In [3]: chr(234)    # Not what you want?
Out[3]: 'ê'

In [4]: chr(234%122)    # What you want?
Out[4]: 'p'

In [5]: chr(0) # On further inspection, you also need to add a constant when you divide
Out[5]: '\x00'

In [6]: chr(49)    # Try adding 49 after modulo dividing, and that should keep you alphanumeric.
Out[6]: '1'
```

I don't actually know id this will affect your decrytion afterwards, I haven't looked into it, but you might want to think about it.

Answer (score 0):

You're complicating things for yourself unnecessarily by using ordinal numbers. Effectively, you're using an "alphabet" with 256 symbols, while you're only interested in 26.

Ideally, you just want your symbols to range in numbers from 0 to 25 and once you hit 26, you warp around to 0 again. You can achieve this with ordinal numbers, but you have to use the correct offsets.

Now, let's assume you only use upper case letters. Their ordinal numbers range from 65 to 90. So once you hit 91, you want to warp around to 65.

```
if temp3 > 90:
    temp3 -= 26
```

The other problem is that you simply add `temp1` and `temp2`. `temp1` can remain as a number between 65 and 90, but `temp2` is supposed to be the key offset, ranging from 0 to 25. Therefore, when you calculate `temp2`, you should really be doing this

```
temp2 = int(keylist[stringposition-1]) - 65
```

That would conceptually solve your problem, but your algorithm is still not correct. The purpose of the while loop is to extend the length of the keyword to be at least as long as the length of the message. Everything else must be indented 4 spaces to the left so they aren't part of the loop. Explicitly,

```
while len(keyword1)<=len(message1):
    keyword1+=keyword1
newkeyword=keyword1[:len(message1)]

for mesletter in message1:
    keynumber = ord(keyletter)
    stringofnumbs.append(mesnumber)

for keyletter in newkeyword:
    keynumber = ord(keyletter)
    keylist.append(keynumber)

    temp1 = int(stringofnumbs[stringposition])
    temp2 = int(keylist[stringposition]) - 65
    temp3 = temp2+temp1
    if temp3 > 90:
        temp3 -= 26
    encdec.append(temp3)

    stringposition += 1

etc
```

In the above code block I want to point some more mistakes I corrected. You're supposed to iterate over `newkeyword`, not `keyword1` and you also have to increase the `stringposition` counter with each letter you go through.

---

For a more efficient and less complex algorithm, consider posting your code to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), for, well, a review, and learn from the feedback you get.

While not the best way to code this, there is still some basic tidying up you can do while keeping your code the same. Basically, once you get your message and keyword to be the same length, you can iterate over the pairs of letters and on-the-fly calculate the encrypted letter, so to store just that in a list. There is no reason to store the intermediate steps, such as turning the message and keyword into lists of numbers.

```
if message1.isalpha() and keyword1.isalpha():
    message1 = message1.upper()
    keyword1 = keyword1.upper()

    if len(keyword1) < len(message1):
        keyword1 = keyword1 * (len(message1) / len(keyword1)) + keyword1
    keyword1 = keyword1[:len(message1)]

    for m, k in zip(message1, keyword1):
        encrypted = ord(m) + (ord(k) - 65)
        if encrypted > 90:
            encrypted -= 26
        encdec.append(chr(encrypted))

    print ('\nThe endcoded text is:')
    print (''.join(encdec))
```